# System of Linear Equations From Exponential

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I find a system of linear equations from fitting $y=de^{ft}$ to $m$ points $(t,y)$? I know that $de^{ft}=d\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{f^nt^n}{n!}$ but am not sure how many terms to take, or how to represent it as $Ax=b$.

Answer (score 0):

$\log y=\log d+ft$. Now each point $(t,y)$ gives you a linear equation in the two unknowns $\log d$ and $f$.

E.g., if $y=3$ when $t=7$, then you get the equation $$\log3=\log d+7f$$

Comment: How would I represent that in the form Ax=b? b would be the equivalent log(y) points.

Comment: It's a system of linear equations in the unknowns $\log d$ and $f$. How do you usually represent a system of linear equations in the form $Ax=b$?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know. Do you have a good reference? It may be easier to represent the exponential over a small closed interval [0,1], using only the quadratic terms from the polynomial expansion in order to obtain an approximation. Unfortunately, I don't know how to put that into Ax=b form either.

Comment: @AmyNord. Do not do that but use a log transform as Gerry Myerson commented

Comment: So, how would I solve for overconstrained d and f points in Ax=b form in curve fitting to solve for d and f? My initial guess is [log(d) f; 0 0]*[1;t]=log(y), but that approach only solves for a single point.

Comment: Every Linear Algebra textbook ever written will tell you how to represent a system of linear equations in the form $Ax=b$, Amy, and the more recent ones will also tell you how to find the "least squares" solution to an overdetermined system. There are probably a few thousand websites that will do the same. You've got the keywords & keyphrases – go have a look, and when you've learned how to do it, come back here to post an answer to your own question! [but I have to wonder how you have stumbled across this problem, when it seems to go well beyond anything you have ever studied.]

Comment: Making any progress, Amy?

Comment: Come on, Amy, I'm trying to help – please, meet me halfway!